# how can mysql compare and between

Tags: mysql

I use this query to compare what is missing in the other database

```
SELECT a.name FROM newdb AS a LEFT JOIN database AS b ON a.name = b.name WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

I would like to add between now

```
SELECT * FROM newdb WHERE ctime BETWEEN 1576882800 AND 1576969200 ORDER BY ctime DESC
```

how can i do this in one command?

with this command he makes mistakes:

```
SELECT a.name FROM newdb AS a LEFT JOIN database AS b ON a.name = b.name WHERE b.name IS NULL WHERE ctime BETWEEN 1576882800 AND 1576969200
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use this new condition in the `WHERE` clause because this would convert the `LEFT` join to an `INNER` join.
Add the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.name 
FROM newdb AS a LEFT JOIN database AS b 
ON a.name = b.name AND b.ctime BETWEEN 1576882800 AND 1576969200
WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

or use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.name FROM newdb AS a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM database AS b 
  WHERE a.name = b.name AND b.ctime BETWEEN 1576882800 AND 1576969200
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second Where to "AND"

```
SELECT a.name FROM newdb AS a LEFT JOIN database AS b ON a.name = b.name WHERE b.name IS NULL AND ctime BETWEEN 1576882800 AND 1576969200
```